# When is 'this' not in scope during named member function overload resolution?

Tags: c++, c++14, overloading, overload-resolution

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Call_to_a_named_function):

> Call to a named function
>
> <...> If the expression E is a primary expression, the name is looked up following normal rules for function calls (which may involve ADL). The function declarations found by this lookup are (due to the way lookup works) either: <...>
>
> b) all member functions of some class T, in which case, if this is in scope and refers to T, *this is used as the implied object argument. Otherwise (if this is not in scope or does not point to T), a fake object of type T is used as the implied object argument, and if overload resolution subsequently selects a non-static member function, the program is ill-formed.

It seems that the second case is about `func(arg)` calls inside methods. When could `this` be not in the scope for such cases?

Or is it talking not only about `func(arg)`-like stuff in methods?

Comment: The missing `)` in b) is disturbing... *Otherwise (if this is not in scope or...* edit: added it :)

Comment: Not all methods are instance methods!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When could `this` be not in the scope for such cases?

Static member functions.

Comment: I guess explicit mentioning of static member functions in reference could've made things much clearer :) but ok

Comment: @Barry would it be correct also to include pure virtual functions for abstract classes?

Comment: @codekaizer How would you be in the body of a pure virtual function?

Comment: @Barry, I was referring to this statement: "does not point to T".

Comment: @codekaizer Does not point to `T` means calling some *other* class' member function, as opposed to our own.

Comment: Or `friend` functions defined in the class body.